# Illegal character in javascript with php header

Tags: javascript, php, bundle

I am using php to bundle javascript and CSS files.

```
...
$js_files = ['path/to/script.js', 'path/to/jquery.js'];

header( "Content-type: application/javascript" );

foreach($js_files as $path){
   echo file_get_contents($path);
}
...
```

But when I add them to my HTML page:

```
<script src="http://localhost:63342/project/assets/assets.php"></script>
```

it gives me syntax error `Uncaught SyntaxError: illegal character U+0001`

```
...function(){
   S.event.add(this�Yÿø��, t, i, r, n)
}...
```

`�Yÿø��` is an illegal string, but my original code is correct:

```
...function(){
   S.event.add(this, t, i, r, n)
}...
```

also tried `readfile()` and `mb_convert_encoding()` for encoding but still not working!

## Edit

Manually it's working correctly:

```
<script src="http://localhost:63342/project/assets/jQuery/jquery.3.6.js"></script>
```

Comment: You've to correct the encoding of the _file_ to match what the Content-Type header says about encoding.

Comment: Encoding is correct, with direct URL is correct but with content type it's not correct

Comment: Compare the HTTP headers that control how the encoding is being interpreted for both methods. The problem *is* somewhere there. Compare the raw output with a hex editor if still in doubt.

Comment: Character encodings are only partially convertable. Considering there's a PHP directive controlling the Content-Type header, it's the smallest nuisance to save the file with the same encoding instead of setting the header separately for all the pages.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My problem didn't solve, so I put bundles in a file named ```bundle.js``` and redirected to the file URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the header like that:
`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

to avoid the problem.